# How do I run Lighthouse CLI during tests in Django?

Tags: django, lighthouse

I would like to run Lighthouse CLI during tests in Django. By default, Django tests don't run a server that can respond to HTTP requests, so this is not possible.

How can I run Lighthouse CLI during Django tests?

Comment: Note that you should still do performance testing on your production server, not just your developer machine, to test the real performance of your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, install Lighthouse CLI:

```
$ npm install --save-dev @lhci/cli
```

Then, modify `package.json` to modify the `scripts` section, like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "lhci": "lhci"
  }
}
```

You can run tests against a server that responds to HTTP requests using [`LiveServerTestCase` or `StaticLiveStaticTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase), like this:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
import subprocess

class Example(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
   def test_example(self):
       subprocess.check_call([
           'npm', 'run', '--', 'lhci', 'collect', '--url', self.live_server_url, '--no-lighthouserc',
       ])
       subprocess.check_call([
           'npm', 'run', '--', 'lhci', 'assert',
       ])
       # Optional:
       subprocess.check_call([
           'npm', 'run', '--', 'lhci', 'open',
       ])
```

Now run this command:

```
$ python manage.py test
```

Note that you probably still want to test the performance of the website on the production server, as it may be quite different then the performance of the website on a local developer machine or the test server.